# Print specific lines using sed

Tags: unix, sed

Im trying to print only lines that do not start with a letter from the file "main"

Ive tried `sed -n '/^[a-z]/ /!w' main`
and it gives me "w': event not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many other ways to print lines

```
sed -n '/^[^a-zA-Z]/p' main
sed -n '/^[^a-z]/Ip' main 

awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}!/^[a-z]/' main

grep -vi "^[a-z]" main

ruby -ne 'print unless /^[a-z]/i' main
```

shell

```
while read -r line
do
  case "$line" in
    [^a-zA-Z]*) echo $line;;
  esac
done < main
```

Comment: What about printing say alphabets between a and z if you have them typed out in a text file

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` as requested:

```
sed '/^[[:alpha:]]/d' main
```

or

```
sed -n '/^[^[:alpha:]]/p' main
```

or

```
sed -n '/^[[:alpha:]]/!p' main
```

*Note*: you could use `[a-z]` inplace of `[[:alpha:]]` but I prefer the latter because it is safe to use across different locales

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v '^[a-z]' main
```

will do it.